# Append a character at the end of a malloc'd string

Tags: c, malloc, buffer

I am looking for a '.' character in a file.
I use the function **read** to look for it.
The problem is that I have a buffer size and I need to loop as long as I don't find the '.' character with `read(fd, buffer, bufferSize)`.
I used **malloc** to allocate the memory for 1 buffer size (`char *buffer = malloc((bufferSize + 1) * sizeof(char))`), but I don't know how many times I'll have to loop.
How can I add memory to the buffer depending on the buffer size loops I'll do ?

Comment: Don't read more than the buffer size, then read again?

Comment: Yeah but I have to save all the characters until the dot in the buffer so I have to add memory every time I loop

Comment: So realloc? @zelph14

Comment: Specify a maximum size and then allocate as much memory as is required for that. Most of the time, the solution to "I don't know how large the x can be" is "find out". Or alternatively just parse til you find the dot, then use fseek to start over now that you know how much memory you need.

Comment: OK I see, I'll check it out. Thanks both of you.

Comment: use `getdelim` function if it is available on your platform

Answer (score 0):

A *string* is not needed.

Instead, to use `read()`, examine its return value to determine how much to search with `memchr()`.

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000
char buffer[BUF_SIZE];

long long loop_count = 0;
ssize_t size_read;
while ((size_read = read(fd, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0) {
  void *dot_address = memchr(buffer, '.', size_read);
  if (dot_address) {
    loop_count += dot_address - buffer;
    printf("Found '.' as offset %lld\n", loop_count);
    break; 
  }
  loop_count += size_read;
}
```

OP later adds in a comment, "I have to save all the characters until the dot in the buffer so I have to add memory every time I loop"

Not sure when continually additional requirements will stop.

Lost interest.